# What takes up graphics memory in Android Profiler?

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, android-bitmap, android-profiler

When I used Android profiler I noticed that graphics were Taking a lot of memory (169 mb) which was making the app extremely slow , and I though that it was caused by Bitmaps so I deleted all the bitmaps in the app and tried again..

and I noticed that graphics were still taking up 60 - 100 mb of RAM , and I would like to know what can cause Memory Drain other than Bitmaps? 
(My App uses google Maps if that helps)

Comment: Google maps use a lot of graphics itself, as it is drawing the maps, which is graphics, but we can't say what drains memory in your app as you told nothing about your app.

Answer (score 3):

Graphics: Memory used for graphics buffer queues to display pixels to the screen, including GL surfaces, GL textures, and so on. (Note that this is memory shared with the CPU, not dedicated GPU memory.)

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html